# Managed Extensibility Framework (MEF) in all tiers

Tags: wpf, wcf, mef

I am in the process of designing a client/server N tier application using `WPF, EF, WCF, SQL`. I want to use the Managed Extensibility Framework (`MEF`) to better manage the "features" that will be included in my application.

I am defining a "feature" to be an end-to-end feature (i.e. UI to Database) which consists of:

- WPF user controls/screens
- "Shared" (client/server) EF model (probably STE's or DBContext)
- WCF service for retrieving and saving data
- Database access class

See diagram. Features A and B are represented end to end.
[image]

In my research, I have some across some good examples for WPF and WCF MEF implementations:

WPF: http://goldytech.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/plug-ins-modules-development-with-mef-part-i/

WCF: http://www.fidelitydesign.net/?p=390#comments

But not both in the same application.

In other words, I want to be able to drop the `UI.FeatureC`/`Entities.FeatureC` on the client and `DataAccess.FeatureC`, and `Entities.FeatureC` on the server and have the application automatically discover the new functionality.

This seems feasible to have MEF parts that define a "feature" present in every tier, right? Or is there a better way to structure this?

Also, I am a little concerned about the database and how it can support a dynamically composed application. I suppose the only option is to make sure the database has the appropriate tables, stored procedures, etc. in place and hang on tight.

Has anyone tried to implement MEF application-wide? Any good references or advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Im trying to do exactly the same. One of the main problems I see with this approach is the shared data model (STE or otherwise). I think (since these are just classes with properties that represent the tables, that you should not MEF them. Regarding application screens and Data Access objects, it's perfectly feasible.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't mean to imply that was going to MEF the entities. Just WPF and WCF "layers". The entities just happen to be common in both.

Comment: if you managed to do this, you might answer your own question. I did mostly what you want(ed)  but I do neither use WCF nor EntityFramework. The way I did it was to have two dlls that only contain interfaces, those are used as Export/Imports for MEF. My application is able to handle multiple database adapters and multiple servers and can combine both (local database + also send data to my 'server'). I did a few stupid things (like not using MVVM or writing my own cross-module/cross-network messanger)  but it does work and is quite stable. What I can't do is add functionality without a restart.